# Simply iterate through XML file, listing nodes for user choice

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I'm trying to iterate through an XML file and display the node name.  The end goal being to have a user select an option and later reference the value of that node.  The code below only outputs the following:

```
> builds
```

I expect it to output this:

```
> LastKnownGood
> Latest
```

What am I doing wrong?

**RunBuild.ps1**

```
$buildsFile = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "$($config.buildspath)/builds.xml");
$builds = $buildsFile.builds;

Write-Host "Available Builds: "
ForEach ($buildVersion in $builds) {
    Write-Host " > $($buildVersion.Name)"
}
```

**builds.xml**

```
<builds>
  <LastKnownGood>Build 8</LastKnownGood>
  <Latest>Build 18</Latest>
</builds>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `ForEach ($buildVersion in $builds)` to `ForEach ($buildVersion in $builds.ChildNodes)` and it is working as expected now.

```
ForEach ($buildVersion in $builds.ChildNodes) {
    Write-Host " > $($buildVersion.LocalName)"
}
```